# Forwading Email using Gmail API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail-api

I'm able to reply back in same mail thread using [Gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send)

For Forwarding email i couldn't find any direct reference. So I requested entire message body passing message ID and tried changing few field using [these as reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.5)

```cs
public ActionResult ForwardEmail(CancellationToken cancellationToken,string ID)
{
    try
    {
        var result = new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new GmailApiFilter()).
        AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken).Result;

        if (result.Credential != null)
        {
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential, ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
            });

            var emailInfoReq = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", ID);
            emailInfoReq.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw; 
            var emailInfoResponse = emailInfoReq.Execute();
            using (MemoryStream rawInStream = new MemoryStream(Base64FUrlDecode(emailInfoResponse.Raw)))
            using (MemoryStream rawOutStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var tempcheck = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(rawInStream);

                tempcheck.ResentFrom.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("", "From@email.com"));
                tempcheck.ResentTo.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("", "to@email.com"));
                tempcheck.ResentDate = DateTime.Now;
                tempcheck.ResentMessageId = tempcheck.MessageId;
   
                tempcheck.WriteTo(rawOutStream);
                emailInfoResponse.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(rawOutStream.ToArray());
            }

            var tempq = service.Users.Messages.Send(emailInfoResponse,"me");
            var temp = tempq.Execute();
            return Json(temp);
        }
        else
        {
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Error

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Precondition Failed [412] Errors [ Message[Precondition Failed] Location[If-Match - header] Reason[conditionNotMet] Domain[global] ]
```

Comment: The FROM email address must match the email account.  It looks like the email account is me and the FROM address is email.com.

Comment: In the google API you can use "me" as a keyword to refer to the mail that is making the HTTP request through the API, so I don't think what @jdweng is 100% right. 
From what I see in your code the problem could be in the creation of the message itself.
Could you please provide the raw message before you convert it to a base64 string? So from there wee could test if the message itself it's valid.

Comment: What I said is correct.  The FROM and email address must match.

Comment: Regarding the FROM part i just used these 
`tempcheck.ResentFrom.AddRange(tempcheck.To);`
To directly move address but it ended up me getting same body email in the thread...having To and From Same @jdweng

Comment: The object is the variable tempcheck.  You have it defined in the Using statement.  To  be able to get the reference to the object after the Using statement you need to define the variable before the Using statement. : var tempcheck; using(your using){ tempcheck = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(rawInStream); }